# Object recognition using LDA and ORB with different sized training image.

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, image-recognition

I'm trying to build a lightweight object recognition system using ORB for feature extraction and LDA for classification. But I'm running into an issue do to the varying size of extracted features.

These are my steps:

1. Extract keypoints using ORB.
2. Extract trainable features in the image by grouping the keypoints. 
   (example of whats being extracted: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AoyGg.jpg)
3. Train the recognizer with the extracted features. (This is where problems arise)
4. Classify objects in an image from the wild.

If I attempt to create a generalized matrix using cv::gemm, I get an exception due to the varying sizes. My first thought was to just to normalize all the images by resizing them, but this causes a lot of accuracy issues when objects have similar small features.

Is there any solution to this? Is LDA an appropriate method for this? I know it's commonly used with facial recognition algorithms such as fisherfaces.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LDA requires **fixed length features**, as do most optimization and machine learning methods.  You could resize the image patches to be a fixed size, but that is probably not going to be a good feature.  Normally people use a scale invariant feature such as [SIFT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scale-invariant_feature_transform).  You also might try a color histogram, or some variation of edge detection and spatial histogram binning such as a [GIST](http://cvcl.mit.edu/scene_understanding.html) vector.

It's hard to say if LDA is an appropriate method for this without knowing what you hope to accomplish.  You might also look into using [SVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine), some form of [boosting](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AdaBoost), or just plain nearest neighbor with a large training set.